# How to get rid of everything except letters in python?

Tags: python, list, file, text

I have a text file like this:

Sally ... went .. to the store !!# and bought an apple and a bagel..@@
Then she went home.

---

How do I remove all the extra things like "..." and ".." and "@" and get the words as items in a list?

I tried

```
filename.rstrip().split()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a regular expression. In python, this is done with the `re` module.

`[^a-zA-Z ]` means characters that aren't letters (or space). You can use `re.sub` to replace all of them with whitespace:

```
import re

def remove_non_letters(string):
    return re.sub("[^a-zA-Z] ", " ", string).split()
```

**EDIT:**

Read in the text file with

```
with open('data.txt', 'r') as file:
    string = file.read()
    result = remove_non_letters(string)
```

`result` is the list you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
s = "Sally ... went .. to the store !!# and bought an apple and a bagel..@@ Then  she went home."
s = [i for i in s if ord(i)>=65 and ord(i)<=122 or i==" "]
print("".join(s).split()))
```

essentially,

1. Include only letters that are spaces, or A-Z or a-z in a list
2. Join the letters back into a string
3. Split the string by spaces

Comment: how does this work in terms of text file

Comment: @Iambadatpython Replace first line with `with open("file.txt") as file: s = file.read()` where `file.txt` is your text file.

Comment: doesn't work man, it combines two words together

Comment: cuz my text file had a new line so when it went to next line the last word in the first row combined with the first word in the second row

Comment: @Iambadatpython You need to set up a for loop to go through each line of the file and treat each sentence seperately. Read more [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

Comment: yea but how do i add that with a space in between the two words

Answer (score 0):

I put the content you mentioned in a file and named it "mix_char.txt".  I added two more random lines to test on new lines. Here is how the content of the file looks:

```
Sally ... went .. to the store !!# and bought an apple and a bagel..@@ Then she went home.
Sally ...      @#$#%$#%$%#                  went ..
  to .......A Store #$%#@$in 4567downtown
```

I then used the below snippet of code to read the file and then regex to do the job:
Considering you are looking for only the words comprising of alphabets:

re.sub ->  used to replace a pattern with another

[^a-zA-Z \n]*' ->  Find all the patterns which do **not** contain alphabets, a space and a new line and replace them with nothing (i:e : remove them)

split : Convert the newly created string in to a list.

```
import re
with open('mix_char.txt') as fh:
    str = fh.read()
    print (re.sub('[^a-zA-Z \n]*','',str).split())
```

You can write the modified data back to another file as you need.

Comment: this doesn't work man, it combined two of the words together

Comment: cuz my text file had a new line so when it went to next line the last word in the first row combined with the first word in the second row

Comment: edited my answer ...hope this works for you ...pls take a look

Comment: in case you have any other content in your file, pls paste the whole content in the question